# Why you can't integrate this as it appears in the solution? And why this value is 0?

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, eulers-number-e

I know what they do, but I want to understand why cannot use the silly way that is integrating e.
Also, I don't understand why f(3) is 0, I mean, it would be close to 0, but not cero right?
[image]

Comment: Who said $f(3)=0$?  $F(3)$ is a constant, so its derivative is $0$.  And how would you integrate $e^{-x^2}$?

Comment: $F(3)$ is not $0$, but it's independent of $t$, so it's $t$-derivative is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can't obtain the antiderivative of $e^{-x^2}$, as it requires a special function.

Now you are free to define

$$F'(x)=e^{-x^2}\leftrightarrow F(t):=\int e^{-x^2}dx+C$$ even if you don't have an analytical expression. From this, the definite integral

$$\int_t^3 e^{-x^2}dx=F(3)-F(t)$$

and the derivative

$$\frac d{dt}\int_t^3 e^{-x^2}dx=\frac d{dt}F(3)-\frac d{dt}F(t).$$

The rest is yours.

Answer (score 0):

[Yves Daoust](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/65203/yves-daoust) is correct. This is just an alternate description.

Without knowing how to integrate f(x), another function, say, F(t), can be defined as being the result of that unknown integration:
$F(t)\text{ is }\int f(x) \, dx+C_1$, where $C_1$ is some unknown constant.

The inverse operation of integration is differentiation.

Now, let us do the problem using that special "undefined" function.

$\frac{\partial \left(\left(C_1+F(3)\right)-\left(C_1+F(t)\right)\right)}{\partial t}$

$\frac{\partial (F(3)-F(t))}{\partial t}$

$\frac{\partial F(3)}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial F(t)}{\partial t}$

The first term is $0$ because the derivative of a constant is $0$.

$-\frac{\partial F(t)}{\partial t}$

Since integration and differentiation are inverse operations except that integration generates unknown constants (kind of like one may not divide by zero). This becomes:

$-e^{-x^2}$ evaluated for $x$ at $t$. Which gives the answer $-e^{-t^2}$.

In this case, the special function, with a normalization so that the area under the curve to the x-axis is $1$ is known as the error function and commonly written as: $\int e^{-x^2} \, dx=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}(x)$. The curve is known as the Gaussian and the function and curve are commonly encountered in statistics.

I know $\LaTeX$ and MathJax did some rearrangement of my input. I regret that result.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution, though correct, is contributing to your confusion. You can do all this without even mentioning the $3$. One part of the *fundamental theorem of calculus* says that when you differentiate an integral with respect to it's upper limit you recover the integrand:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \int_c^t f(x)dx = f(t) .
$$
This result does not depend on or mention the constant lower limit $c$.

You solve your problem by replacing $\int_t^3$ by $-\int_3^t$.